# how to make layout work in grails when link has id (or not)

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp, param

The following is my code in land.gsp page.

```
 <table style="padding: 10 ">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="color: blue">
                        <td>Gname</td>
                        <td>Gowner</td>
                        <td>Device number</td>
                        <td>Edit </td>
                        <td>Delete </td>


                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${Groups.list()}" status="i" var="groupsInstance">
                <g:set var="myid" value="${groupsInstance.id}"></g:set>
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: groupsInstance, field: "gname")}</td>
                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: groupsInstance, field: "gowner")}</td>
                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: groupsInstance, field: "devicenum")}</td>
                        <td><g:link action="edit" id="${groupsInstance.id}">Edit</g:link></td>
                        <td><g:link action="deleteme" id="${groupsInstance.id}">Delete</g:link></td>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

But When I click on edit The layout of the page is not working( javascript, images, styles). But the id get passed to the edit.gsp page correctly. When I change

```
<td><g:link action="edit" id="${groupsInstance.id}">Edit</g:link></td>
```

to

```
<td><g:link action="edit" >Edit</g:link></td>
```

that is without passing id and clicking on edit will give a page with correct Layout. Following is my edit action

```
def edit(Long id) {
        def groupsInstance = Groups.get(id)
        if (!groupsInstance) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'groups.label', default: 'Groups'), id])
            redirect(action: "list")
            return
        }

        [groupsInstance: groupsInstance]
    }
```

Where I went wrong? I want to pass the id to edit page with all correct layout.

Answer (score 2):

Try to view the source html in your browser, that might give you a clue to what is wrong.

Comment: I checked it. It doest loading any of the javascript,Images,css etc. but without passing id in <g:link> it is loading the same javascript and images. I dont understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try to adopt with below option based on your preference :

```
<g:link action="/conference/participated" id="${it.conference.id}" 
               params="[foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo']">My Link!</g:link>
```

I see in your code that when

```
def groupsInstance = Groups.get(id)
        if (!groupsInstance) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'groups.label', default: 'Groups'), id])
            redirect(action: "list")
            return
```

You have redirected it to a list page , am sure list page has different layout setting and that is the change , please check on that and let me know!

Comment: plz check my edit in question.. my problem is with changing the layout when I pass the id.

Comment: please be specifc to grails that specify the controller name and action on glink...

Comment: I dont want to change the layout of the edit page. But the layout is changing when I pass the id to the edit page from the land.gsp. I dont understand what is changing the layout. when I checked the html in my browser, I understood that it is not loading the javascript, images, styles that i given to the page

Comment: No.. am using the same layout there and the same styles. without the the if statement also giving me the same problem. its with the id that I am passing in the land.gsp. If I am not passing the id it is working perfectly.

Comment: its working perfectly because it doent redirect to list page when id is not used ..dont be nutts :) ,, something is wrong with your list page and redirection.

Comment: @ danielad without that if closure also I am getting the same problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51253/discussion-between-danielad-and-sag)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your edit action it looks like if no id is supplied then you redirect to the list action and you say the layout is fine there.  If the id is specified (and it is valid) you are rendering the edit view.  I expect that the problem is in your edit.gsp which is not currently shown in your description.